# Incremental storage to netcdf using xarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have created 3 data arrays and 1 dataset out of it using Python xarray.

```py
da_test = xr.DataArray(rt, dims=['dtime', 'lat', 'lon'], coords={'dtime': tAxis, 'lat': Y,
                                   'lon': X},)

da_test2 = xr.DataArray(rt1, dims=['dtime', 'lat', 'lon'], coords={'dtime': tAxis, 'lat': Y,
                                   'lon': X},)

da_test3 = xr.DataArray(rt2, dims=['dtime', 'lat', 'lon'], coords={'dtime': tAxis, 'lat': Y,
                                   'lon': X},)

ds = xr.Dataset({"test" : da_test, "test2" : da_test2, "test3" : da_test3})
```

Now I am trying to save the dataset to netcdf file. If the file exists, I open the dataset, concatenate the current dataset along 'dtime' axis and store it back to the netcdf. I have specified 'dtime' as unlimited dimension to make it extendable along that dimension.

```py
dsList = [ds]

if os.path.isfile('./'+outFileName):
    diskDS = xr.open_dataset(outFileName, group="/satGrp")
    dsList.append(diskDS)
    finalDS = xr.concat(dsList, dim="dtime")
    diskDS.close()
else:
    finalDS = ds

# Setting up compression and writing to nc file
comp = dict(zlib=True, complevel=5)
encoding = {var: comp for var in finalDS.data_vars}
finalDS.to_netcdf(outFileName, group="/satGrp", mode='a', format="NETCDF4", engine='h5netcdf', unlimited_dims=["dtime"], encoding=encoding)
```

I am trying to simulate a use case where the script will run every half hour and update netcdf with updated datasets. The first pass goes through successfully and the dataset is stored. But when I run it the next time, I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xr.py", line 87, in <module>
    finalDS.to_netcdf(outFileName, group="/satGrp", mode='a', format="NETCDF4", engine='h5netcdf', unlimited_dims=["dtime"], encoding=encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1384, in to_netcdf
    compute=compute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 886, in to_netcdf
    unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 929, in dump_to_store
    unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 271, in store
    self.set_dimensions(variables, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 343, in set_dimensions
    "%r (%d != %d)" % (dim, length, existing_dims[dim]))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType
```

Dataset stored in first pass:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dtime: 1, lat: 30, lon: 20)
Coordinates:
  * dtime    (dtime) datetime64[ns] 2019-09-18T12:06:00.298381
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Data variables:
    test     (dtime, lat, lon) float64 ...
    test2    (dtime, lat, lon) float64 ...
    test3    (dtime, lat, lon) float64 ...
```

Current run dataset in memory:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dtime: 1, lat: 30, lon: 20)
Coordinates:
  * dtime    (dtime) datetime64[ns] 2019-09-18T12:07:10.351870
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Data variables:
    test     (dtime, lat, lon) float64 47.42 977.8 168.2 ... 685.2 777.5 412.6
    test2    (dtime, lat, lon) float64 105.4 2.173e+03 373.8 ... 1.728e+03 916.9
    test3    (dtime, lat, lon) float64 26.32 542.7 93.36 ... 380.3 431.5 229.0
```

Concatenated dataset in memory:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (dtime: 2, lat: 30, lon: 20)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
  * dtime    (dtime) datetime64[ns] 2019-09-18T12:07:10.351870 2019-09-18T12:06:00.298381
Data variables:
    test     (dtime, lat, lon) float64 47.42 977.8 168.2 ... 318.1 977.0 655.4
    test2    (dtime, lat, lon) float64 105.4 2.173e+03 ... 2.171e+03 1.456e+03
    test3    (dtime, lat, lon) float64 26.32 542.7 93.36 ... 176.6 542.3 363.7
```

While debugging I found the following in xarray common.py:

```
odict_items([('dtime', 2), ('lat', 30), ('lon', 20)])
<h5netcdf.Dimensions: lat=30, lon=20, dtime=None>
```

So the check is failing at existing_dims['dtime'] where its getting None.

Funny thing is, if I change mode to 'w' in to_netcdf call, the updates are smooth. But since I want to have multiple groups in the netcdf, I really need to use 'a' mode.

Look forward to ideas to mitigate this issue.